# How to compare two dataframes and put the counted unique values in a first dataframe's column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different (geo)dataframes, one has 690 and the other has 1826 rows. The first one is a grouped based on the nearness (spatial near) of the second dataframe. Thus, they bound with FID_1 and NEAR_FID columns. Every FID_1 in the first dataframe corresponds to at least 2 NEAR_FIDs in the second dataframe. My challenge is to count the number of NEAR_FIDs in the second dataframe and put as a row in the first one. I am using python 3.5+. Thanks for any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be achieved using the`merge` function in pandas. Here is the code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'FID_1':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NEAR_FID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3]})

df_freq = df2.NEAR_FID.value_counts().reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df_freq, df1, how='inner', left_on=['index'], right_on=['FID_1'])
df
       index  NEAR_FID  FID_1
0      1         4      1
1      3         2      3
2      2         2      2
```

You can remove any of the column index or FID_1 to get your desired output.

For more on merge function look at the official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)
 and for a very good explanation of its working look [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

EDIT 1:
Merge function only accepts Dataframes and not series. So, if your data is in series format, convert it to dataframe first.
You can check the type of your data by:

```
print(type(df2))
```

And that should output `pandas.core.series.Series`

Use this to change it to a dataframe:

```
df = df.to_frame().reset_index()
```

Comment: @bkshi.Thanks for your help. I am facing an error though while running the code here:ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Also, we have calculated the 'df_freq' but we are not using the following line of code. Thus, I assume the 'df_freq' should go inside the nect line.

Comment: Yep corrected it. Try doing it now, it should work.

Comment: seems I do not have the 'NEAR_FID' field anymore after the code is run. The 'df' has no row called 'NEAR_FID'. Do you see why it can be?

Comment: Probably your dataset is a bit different, can you edit your question with the exact data and not image? Also, there won't be a new row, instead a new column of 'NEAR_FID'. You should also check the name of your dataframes that they don't get mixed up!

Comment: Thanks, buddy. It is working as it expected.

Comment: No problem, you may upvote the answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: Sure. But so far I do not have the reputation yet.